# Have i miswired when trying to insert a new node at the middle of doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Structure looked like:

```
class DList{
private:
        struct Elem {
        Elem *prev, *next;
        };
        Elem *_head, *_tail;
}
```

Now I have two existing node: cur and cur->next, and i wanna insert a new node ins between them. Here's what i did:

```
    cur->next = ins;//step-1-1 cur
    ins->prev = cur;//step-1-2 cur

    ins->next = cur->next;//step-2-1 cur->next
    cur->next->prev = ins;//step-2-2 cur->next
```

The problem is in further traverse loop of my program my pointer cannot reach _tail anymore. Did i mishook something in my insertion part? (The loop works perfectly once i comment the insertion at middle codes above)

Comment: By the time you do `ins->next = cur->next`, you've already set `cur->next = ins`. So you end up with `ins->next == ins`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  step-2-1 is set for hook ins and original cur->next node, there are two so i think i have to hook with both

Comment: Well, yes, that's your intent - but you've lost your pointer to **original** `cur->next` node by that time. `cur->next` no longer points to said original node, but to `ins` instead.

Comment: hmm, so i need to create another pointer (call temp) to take cur->next, then manipulate temp and cur?

Comment: That would be one way to do it, yes. It's possible to manage without an extra variable, by making changes in just the right order. Determining the correct order is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, there's a miswiring here. Let's draw pictures!

Imagine things look like this, initially:

```
             curr
              |
              v
         +----------+                         +----------+
         |   next   | ----------------------> |   next   | --> ...
         +----------+                         +----------+
 ... <-- |   prev   | <---------------------- |   prev   | <-- ...
         +----------+                         +----------+
                           +----------+
                           |   next   |
                           +----------+
                           |   prev   |
                           +----------+
                                ^
                                |
                                ins
```

First, you execute `cur->next = ins;`, which does this:

```
             curr
              |
              v
         +----------+                         +----------+
         |   next   | -----------+            |   next   | --> ...
         +----------+            |            +----------+
 ... <-- |   prev   | <----------+----------- |   prev   | <-- ...
         +----------+            v            +----------+
                           +----------+
                           |   next   |
                           +----------+
                           |   prev   |
                           +----------+
                                ^
                                |
                                ins
```

Notice that we no longer have a pointer to the element that was originally after `curr` - oops! That'll be a problem later.

Now, we do `ins->prev = curr;`, which looks like this:

```
             curr
              |
              v
         +----------+                         +----------+
         |   next   | -----------+            |   next   | --> ...
         +----------+            |            +----------+
 ... <-- |   prev   | <----------+----------- |   prev   | <-- ...
         +----------+            v            +----------+
               ^           +----------+
               |           |   next   |
               |           +----------+
               +---------- |   prev   |
                           +----------+
                                ^
                                |
                                ins
```

Now, we write `ins->next = curr->next;`. But oops! Notice that `curr->next` points to `ins`, so we just added a cycle in here:

```
             curr
              |
              v
         +----------+                         +----------+
         |   next   | -----------+            |   next   | --> ...
         +----------+            |            +----------+
 ... <-- |   prev   | <----------+----------- |   prev   | <-- ...
         +----------+            v            +----------+
               ^           +----------+
               |           |   next   | --+
               |           +----------+   |
               +---------- |   prev   | <-+
                           +----------+
                                ^
                                |
                                ins
```

And finally, you write `cur->next->prev = ins;` But oops! `curr->next` is still `prev`, so we get another cycle:

```
             curr
              |
              v
         +----------+                         +----------+
         |   next   | -----------+            |   next   | --> ...
         +----------+            |            +----------+
 ... <-- |   prev   | <----------+----------- |   prev   | <-- ...
         +----------+            v            +----------+
                           +----------+
                       +-> |   next   | --+
                       |   +----------+   |
                       +-- |   prev   | <-+
                           +----------+
                                ^
                                |
                                ins
```

The issue here is that you lose track of the cell pointed at by `curr->next` after the first assignment, so you lose the ability to look in the right place.

What if you start off by writing something like this?

```
DList* next = curr->next;
```

and then use `next` instead of `curr->next` in some of these contexts?

Comment: No worries! This approach of drawing pictures is super valuable when working with linked lists. I've been doing this for years and still find it helpful myself!

Answer (score 1):

Key is to not lose the values which are going to be used later on. Your first line of code `cur->next = ins;` makes you lose the original value  `(cur->next)`; thereafter you really don't know who will be `next` to `ins`.

Use this logic to insert a new node in middle. Lets say initially,

```
cur - cur->next  
    |
  [ins]
```

Do,

```
ins->next = cur->next;
```

(cur)  (ins) - (cur->next)    *{Assume - for next, and = for next and prev}*

```
cur->next = ins;
```

(cur) - (ins) - (cur->next)

```
ins->prev = cur;
```

cur = ins - (cur->next)

```
ins->next->prev = ins;
```

cur = ins = (cur->next)